# Why so many "end" statements in this code [elixir]

Tags: syntax, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working through the Programming Elixir book and on one of the examples I got a compile error that I was missing an `end`, so I added an `end` and it worked..

Thing is, I can't figure out what it is closing!

But it works!???

Is this a weird elixir thing? Whats going on?

```
 defmodule Rumbl.Repo do
 @moduledoc """
 In memory repository
  """

  def all(Rumbl.User) do
    [%Rumbl.User{id: "1", name: "Jose", username: "josevalim", password: "elixir"},
     %Rumbl.User{id: "2", name: "Alison", username: "allygrrl", password: "elixir123"},
     %Rumbl.User{id: "3", name: "Susan", username: "susanQ",password: "elixir321"}]
  end

  def all(_module), do: [] 

  def get(module, id) do
    Enum.find all(module), fn map -> map.id == id end
  end

  def get_by(module, params) do 
    Enum.find all(module), fn map -> 
      Enum.all?(params, fn {key, val} -> Map.get(map, key) == val end)
  end
end
end
```

Comment: The last `end` is to close the `module`. The two `end` preceding that one are incorrectly indented. They both belong to the function `get_by`, the inner most one is to close the `fn map ->` whereas the outermost `end` of the two is to close the function `get_by`. The answer of Bozydar shows the end result if you were to correctly indent those two `end`.

Comment: One more point--if you're using Elixir 1.6 or later, running the formatter over your code will help to spot these errors and indent everything correctly as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't closed `fn map -> ...` in `get_by/2`
So it should look like this:

```
def get_by(module, params) do 
  Enum.find all(module), fn map -> 
    Enum.all?(params, fn {key, val} -> Map.get(map, key) == val end)
  end  # <- end needed here
end
```

Comment: I see now, feels silly.. 
Still don't get why doesn't the "def all(_module), do: []" need a closing end?? 
I thought that was the problem before...   Also why is Enum or map treated like a do/end ? I thought end was exclusive to do I guess...

Comment: Elixir is a layer on top of Erlang and the language developers jump through hoops to keep it lean.  The `end` of `def module` is one of the little prices we pay for such 'acrobatics'.

Comment: @ReedJones The `end` is for closing the anonymous function, not the Enum function.